# I need help with breaking a object

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers

Hey guys can someone tell me how to make a  pillar for example to fall apart into squares, like if someone hit it with a hammer?

Comment: Try the Cell Fracture addon + rigid body simulation. If you are asking for something else though, here are some other ways to destroy objects in blender:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJFE2pb0Ri4

Answer (score 1):

Use the Cell Fracture add-on, it's the most common way to break stuff in Blender.

Once you've enabled it, click your object, press the spacebar and search "Cell Fracture".

It may change your object into something like this, depending on the settings you use for the fracturing.(if you can't see your fractured object, look at the next layer) [image]

The fun part begins: select all the fractures and turn them all into Rigid Bodies, and check the "Animated". (make sure all of the fractures have the "Animated" checked, or else the whole thing will fall apart without collision)

Once you've set up your hammer or anything that breaks your object, make sure that is a Rigid Body too, with the "Animated" box checked.

Animate your colliding object through your breaking object, then you animate the "Animate" checkbox. If you don't know how to do that, just hover your mouse over the "Animated" checkbox and click I. Then go the the keyframe where your colliding object is just about to collide with your breaking object, then click I again. Go to the next keyframe, uncheck the "Animated" box and press I again. Now it works!

Do the same thing with your breaking object, but make sure it is well timed, because your breaking object might get destroyed before the impact. Now have fun and amuse yourself with your destroying things!

Comment: Thank you, I will have fun now, I got inspired to learn how to do it by watching a youtuber play house flipper and I want to eventually make a game, but I wanna learn everything I can first. Thank you again

Comment: I like your theme, @RogueLotus4. Which one is it?

Comment: @seaturtle I used the North theme.